# Changing a SQL Server function to work with multiple records

Tags: sql, function, sql-server-2014

I have a function that I use to compute the number of days that a patient is unavailable in order to reduce the number of days they have breached a waiting times deadline.

The function is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDaysUnavailable] 
(
    @intRef     int
)
RETURNS int

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @ReturnValue        int
DECLARE @dtUnavailFrom  datetime
DECLARE @dtUnavailTo        datetime
DECLARE @dtRefRcvd      datetime

SELECT @dtUnavailFrom = UnavailableFrom FROM Referrals WHERE ReferralID = @intRef
SELECT @dtUnavailTo = UnavailableTo FROM Referrals WHERE ReferralID = @intRef
SELECT @dtRefRcvd = ReferralReceivedDate FROM Referrals WHERE ReferralID = @intRef

IF ISNULL(@dtUnavailFrom,'') = '' OR ISNULL(@dtUnavailTo,'') = ''
  BEGIN
    SELECT @ReturnValue = 0
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    IF @dtRefRcvd > @dtUnavailFrom
      BEGIN
        SELECT @ReturnValue = DATEDIFF(day,@dtRefRcvd, @dtUnavailTo)
      END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
        SELECT @ReturnValue = DATEDIFF(day,@dtUnavailFrom, @dtUnavailTo)
      END
    END

RETURN @ReturnValue
END
```

As you can see it works out the difference between the date that the person is unavailable to and either the date they are unavailable from or the date their referral was received.  This was fine using my original structure whereby the 2 date fields were in the main table.  The problem with this was that there could only ever be 1 period of unavailability.

I have now changed the table structure so that the unavailability periods are in their own table which has a 1-to-many relationship with the main table.

But now I can't figure out how to get my function to cope withe new structure.  I basically need to be able to pull every row in the unavailability  table that relates to the parent record and them loop through each row, summing up the unavailability and returning the total at the end.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return value from this subquery

```
Select Sum(Datediff(day,UnavailableFrom,UnavailableTo)) as Summary from UnavailabilityTbl where ReferralID = @intRef Group by ReferralID
```